# How to remove stop words with attachment processor in Elastisearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to following index template:

```
PUT _index_template/aclimdb_1
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "aclimdb-*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "index": {
        "max_result_window": "25000"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "attachment.content": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "class": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": 1,
  "priority": 500,
  "composed_of": [
  ],
  "_meta": {
    "description": "aclImdb index"
  }
}
```

and the following mappings:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "attachment": {
          "properties": {
            "content": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "content_length": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "language": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "class": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "filename": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the following ingest pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "attachment": {
      "field": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    "html_strip": {
      "field": "attachment.content"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to remove the stop words from the terms list when I upload the documents.How can I do that?

Do I have to do it in the ingest pipeline or in the settings of the index template?

Thank you very much for your help

**Edit:**
Thanks to the answer below I found a way to solve the problem. Here is my new index template.

```
PUT _index_template/aclimdb_1
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "aclimdb-*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "index": {
        "max_result_window": "25000"
      },
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "english_stop": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": "_english_"
          },
          "english_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "english"
          },
          "english_possessive_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "possessive_english"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "english_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "english_possessive_stemmer",
              "lowercase",
              "english_stop",
              "english_stemmer"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "attachment.content": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english_analyzer"
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "class": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": 1,
  "priority": 500,
  "composed_of": [],
  "_meta": {
    "description": "aclImdb index"
  }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way how I could achieve the same result?

Now I have the next challenge. I would like to filter out all numeric values. How would a filter to achieve that look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a field with the analyzer stop word english. Then, when you index your token not have the stop words.

Read more about **[stop words filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html)**.

Example:

```
PUT idx_stop_words
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop_filter": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "english_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

GET idx_stop_words/_analyze
{
  "field": "content",
  "text": "the woman in the window"
}
```

Token:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "woman",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "window",
      "start_offset": 17,
      "end_offset": 23,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```